# Print full path to last modified file in a given location

Tags: bash, shell

## Background

I've provided two simple functions that I use to print a full path to the last modified file within a directory. I don't code in bash frequently so I'm looking for a generic feedback on what to do / avoid when writing small utility functions in bash.

## Code

### Last file

The function prints a full path to last modified file in a specific or current directory (if no path is provided).

```bash
function last_file () {
    if [[ -n "$1" ]]
    then
        (cd "$1" && echo "$(pwd -P)/$(ls -rt | tail -n 1)")
    else 
        echo "$(pwd -P)/$(ls -rt | tail -n 1)"
    fi
}
```

### Last download

As above but prints last modified file in the `~/Downloads`.

```bash
function last_download () {
    (cd ~/Downloads && last_file)

}
```

Comment: There isn't much code to look at but hey, small questions can gain small answers I suppose :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes That's true, I was thinking that I may be relaying on subshells too frivolously so I was wondering if someone is going to comment on that...

Comment: Hmm, OK, maybe a good idea to indicate why you chose that instead of one of the other options like braces in that case.

Comment: `last_download() { last_file ~/Downloads; }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to remove the duplicated command.

```bash
last_file () {
    (
        set -e
        [[ -n "$1" ]] && cd "$1"
        printf '%s/%s\n' "$(pwd -P)" "$(ls -rt | tail -n 1)"
    )
}
```

- The whole body is run in a subshell.
- `set -e` makes the subshell abort if the given argument is not a directory. You did something similar with `cd "$1" && echo ...`
- [printf is better than echo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/4667)

Answer (score 6):

### Test argument count

Testing `[ -n "$1" ]` is a failure if we're running with `set -u` (and I do recommend `set -u` in general).  You can test `"${1-}"` instead to safely get an empty string when given no arguments.

But really, we should return an error if we have too many arguments, so I suggest `case $# in`  instead.

### Prefer `head` to `tail`

In a pipe, using `head` can be more efficient than `tail`, since the writing side can stop (with `SIGPIPE`) when `head` has enough lines and exits.  In this case, removing `-r` from the `ls` command allows us

### Don't process the output of `ls`

`ls` will print file names separated by newlines, and those newlines are indistinguishable from any newline that might be within a file name.

The other idiosyncrasy of `ls` is that it will omit all names that begin with `.`, which *might* be what you want, but that wasn't mentioned.

### `function` keyword is unnecessary

Most shell scripters omit the `function` keyword, for a more portable function definition.

---

## Alternative implementation

This is something I've looked at, and have now [posted for its own review](/q/282030/75307).

I created a function that takes one or more arguments and returns the newest file of those, using `test` to compare modification times (thus avoiding any problems with embedded newlines):

```
last_mtime() {
    test -e "${1-}" || return 1
    last=$1; shift
    for i
    do
        test -e "$i" || return 1
        test "$last" -nt "$i" || last=$i
    done
    printf '%s\n' "$last"
}
```

Then the downloads function looks like

```
last_download() {
    # N.B. ignores anything starting with '.', unless 'dotglob'
    # is set in Bash options
    last_mtime ~/Downloads/*
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using subshells frivolously

In a comment you expressed concern about using subshells frivolously.
Often there's a tradeoff between using a subshell or writing more complex code to avoid.
There's an overhead of subshells so it's a good practice to avoid them,
when the alternative is simple enough.

An important factor is if the script will be used in a loop or not.
One-off uses of subshell won't be noticeable,
but that can change when called in a nested loop.

For getting the absolute path of *another directory*,
I think it's a fine tradeoff to use a subshell,
because it's very simple to write,
and the alternative is complex and error prone,
that is, computing the same in native Bash,
especially the processing of symbolic links.

I think you did right to separate the cases of the current directory and a different directory, and not using a subshell in the first one, since it's unnecessary.

Aside from the `(cd ...)`, there are other subshells in this code that can be avoided, see the next sections.

#### Consider `$PWD` instead of `pwd -P`

If you don't have a very specific need for the effect of `pwd -P`,
consider using simply `$PWD`.
It's not exactly the same thing with respect to symbolic links,
but it does give you an absolute path that might be good enough for your intents and purposes.

#### Consider `cmd ...` instead of `echo "$(cmd ...)"`

Instead of:

> ```
> echo "$(pwd -P)/$(ls -rt | tail -n 1)"
> ```

You could eliminate one subshell and the echo with the equivalent:

```
ls -t "$(pwd -P)"/* | head -n 1
```

#### Avoiding duplication

As another answer pointed out,
there is duplicate logic in the implementation of the cases of the current directory and another directory.
A simple way to avoid the duplication is a recursive call to the same function, that is `(cd "$1" && last_file)`.
I prefer this over the solution offered in that answer,
because this avoids an unnecessary subshell in the case of the current directory.

#### Error handling

The script doesn't handle errors.
When the specified directory doesn't exist,
it would be better to return a failure explicitly,
otherwise the output might be misleading.

#### Alternative implementation

Putting the above suggestions together, also assuming `set -u` is in effect, as another answer suggested:

```
last_file() {
    if [[ "${1+x}" ]]
    then
        [ -d "$1" ] || return 1
        (cd "$1" && last_file)
    else 
        ls -t "$PWD"/* | head -n 1
    fi
}
```